# Better way to take lots of dot products?

Tags: optimization, julia

I am new to Julia, and not terribly good at programming, sorry if there is an obvious answer I have missed.
I am trying to do a calculation that involves taking a lot of dot products of vectors with three elements, say like this,

```
 function foo()
  z = 0.0
  for i in 1:10000
   z = dot([0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0])
  end
 end
```

But when I run

```
@time foo()
```

I get

```
0.001010 seconds (20.00 k allocations: 1.831 MB)
```

Which seems like a lot of allocation for this calculation
and considering I need run it not 10000 time but closer to 10^9,
which takes about 5 minutes and allocates gigabytes of memory. I feel 
like it should not allocate so much. I am wrong? Is there a better way to do this that doesn't allocate so much and might be faster?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The allocation comes from the fact that you are creating the arrays like `[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]` each time. If you remove this creation from the loop, it behaves as you expect:

```
function foo2(N=10^4)
    a, b = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    z = 0.0

    for i in 1:N
        z += dot(a, b)
    end

    return z
end

@time foo2()
0.000199 seconds (7 allocations: 368 bytes)

@time foo2(10^7)
0.179523 seconds (8 allocations: 384 bytes)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I just need to rearrange a couple things to get this to work.